# Can I somehow expose state to stateless traits for tests?

Tags: rust

I built a small library which basically has plugin for emulation of certain functions:

```rust
trait ProvideFunctions {
    fn do_a();
    fn do_b(foo: usize) -> ();
}

struct SomeThing<P: ProvideFunctions> {
    _marker: PhantomData<P>
}

struct MainThing<P: ProvideFunctions> {
    // some fields
    some_thing: SomeThing<P>,
    _marker: PhantomData<P>
}

impl<P: ProvideFunctions> MainThing<P> {
   fn do_something(&self) -> () {
        P::do_a();
        P::do_b(1);
        // ...
   }
}
```

The plugged in functions are meant to be stateless, which is however a little bit unfortunate when writing tests, because some state would be definitely useful there (f.e. to track calls, construct something fake etc.)

Without changing the structure substantially I see two options:

- Have some `static` state for tests which feels really bad because the state is in fact only local to the specific test and the test should not run twice and so on ..
- Change the plugin to be stateful. This seems bad however, because all the structs that share the functionality would need some kind of copy of the plugin. Though I trust the compiler to optimize the state away for the real use case, the trait now does in fact encourage statefullness, which is bad as well.

Is there a common solution for this kind of problem? Some other ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stateless trait" a trait describes functionality, it does not define the algorithm used to do that, wether it's stateless or stateful.

Comment: @cafce25 Probably that it doesn't have any methods, only associated functions that don't take a receiver.

Comment: Why won't you just store actual structs and make `Copy` or even `Clone` of them? This will be optimized to nop by the compiler for stateless structs.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the state type as a separate type than the "trait" type and use it very similarly to the `self` receiver type. It's syntactically a bit more noisy but semantically identical. For convenience, use the unit type as the default state type.

```
trait ProvideFunctionsGeneric<T=()> {
    fn do_a(this : &T);
    fn do_b(this: &T, foo: usize) -> ();
}
```

You can define an additional trait with a blanket impl for convenience, to have the same interface as before.

```
trait ProvideFunctions<> {
    fn do_a();
    fn do_b(foo: usize) -> ();
}

impl<T> ProvideFunctions for T where T : ProvideFunctionsGeneric<()> {
    fn do_a()
    {
        <T as ProvideFunctionsGeneric<()>>::do_a(&());
    }
    fn do_b(foo: usize) -> ()
    {
        <T as ProvideFunctionsGeneric<()>>::do_b(&(), foo);
    }
}
```

In your tests you have to handle passing around the state. In your real program, if you want to enforce statelessness, simply consume or provide impls which only use a unit state type.

```
struct MainThing<S, P: ProvideFunctionsGeneric<S>> {
    _marker: PhantomData<P>,
    _state : S,
}

impl<S, P: ProvideFunctionsGeneric<S>> MainThing<S, P> {
   fn do_something(&self) -> () {
        P::do_a(&self._state);
        P::do_b(&self._state, 1);
   }
}


// The type of this function could be more general,
// but we artificially restrict it so that consumers of this module can't see the state
pub fn real_business_logic<P: ProvideFunctionsGeneric>(thing : &MainThing<(), P>)
{
    thing.do_something();
}
```

---

Note: you can do the same with associated types, which you might find more convenient:

```
trait ProvideFunctionsGeneric1 {
    type State;
    fn do_a(this : &Self::State);
    fn do_b(this: &Self::State, foo: usize) -> ();
}

trait ProvideFunctions1<> {
    fn do_a();
    fn do_b(foo: usize) -> ();
}

impl<T> ProvideFunctions1 for T where T : ProvideFunctionsGeneric1<State=()> {
    fn do_a()
    {
        <T as ProvideFunctionsGeneric1>::do_a(&());
    }
    fn do_b(foo: usize) -> ()
    {
        <T as ProvideFunctionsGeneric1>::do_b(&(), foo);
    }
}
```